# Insert record and keep primary key value

Tags: sql, sqlite, primary-key, rowid

I've got a SQLite database and a table that uses an autoincrementing int as the primary key. I've looked through the documentation and it seems that if I perform an INSERT AND REPLACE, it deletes then inserts a record when a duplicate is found.

This is fine, but the problem is that the autoincrementing key continues from where it left off, rather than starting from zero. This means that each time I run that query, the incrementing changes for the record. Is it possible to update the record without changing the primary key? One way I found that works is to delete the table and the primary key index, but that seems overkill and would likely result in a longer time as the table gets bigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the record exists, you could do an UPDATE on it.  This will not change the primary key.

Comment: Is that the most efficient way to do it? I was hoping it would be built in. So will I have to check for each record and double the round trips to the database?

Comment: If you want to keep the primary key....yes.  Maybe you could write a stored procedure to do it in one trip and call that.

Comment: I looked and it seems SQLite doesn't support stored procedures. I'll use this method. Thanks.

Comment: No stored procedures?   Well I guess that's why they call it lite!